# Documentclass `book': How to prevent numbered examples to start over each chapter

Tags: document-classes, linguistics, linguex

So, I am writing my thesis (in linguistics) using the `book` `documentclass` to do this. For my numbered examples I am using the `linguex` package.

```
   \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
      \usepackage{linguex}
   \begin{document}
      \chapter{This is chapter one}
       I have a nice sentence here:
       \ex. This is an example.
       And a nice additional example:
       \ex. This is another example.
       \chapter{This is chapter two}
       This is the most important example in the thesis and I will refer to it often!
      \ex.\label{important} This is a very important example.

      \chapter{This is chapter three}
      As you can see, \Next and \NNext are very different from \ref{important}.
     \ex. This is an example.
     \ex. This is another example.
   \end{document}
```

The counter for the numbered examples now gets reset at the start of each chapter. So the first example in each chapter is now numbered (1). This is not what I'd like since I sometimes need to refer to an example of another chapter and then it is unclear which example I mean exactly. The output of chapter 3 now looks like this. As you can see, the referencing gets confusing.

[image: Output for chapter 3]

Anyone know how to fix/alter this? Ideally Chapter three would look something like:

> As you can see (4) and (5) are very different from (3).
>
> (4) This is an example.
>
> (5) This is another example.

I have read the `linguex` manual but couldn't find any hints towards a solution and I have not been able to find an answer on the Internet..

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I adapted my code to your MWE, see below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to include the `remreset` package, which allows removing counters from the reset list (with the command `\@removefromreset`)

The responsible counter is called `ExNo`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{ExNo}{chapter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is chapter one} I have a nice sentence here:

\ex. This is an example.

And a nice additional example: \ex. This is another example.

\chapter{This is chapter two} This is the most important example in the thesis and I will refer to it often! \ex.\label{important} This is a very important example.

\chapter{This is chapter three} As you can see, \Next and \NNext are very different from \ref{important}. \ex. This is an example.

\ex. This is another example.

\end{document}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}

\ex. Ex. One

\ex. Ex. Two

\chapter{Chapter Two}

\ex. Ex. Three

\end{document}
```

I expect, that subexamples numbering should be reset in every chapter anyway?

Comment: @Emma Did you run `pdflatex` twice? In my version the reference is (3)

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the issue. It is fixed now:)

Comment: @Emma: All's well that end's well ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `\counterwithout{<counter>)(<block>}` from `chngcntr` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithout{ExNo}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is chapter one} I have a nice sentence here:

\ex. This is an example.

And a nice additional example: \ex. This is another example.

\chapter{This is chapter two} This is the most important example in the thesis and I will refer to it often! \ex.\label{important} This is a very important example.

\chapter{This is chapter three} As you can see, \Next and \NNext are very different from \ref{important}. \ex. This is an example.

\ex. This is another example.

\end{document}
```

[image]